# Can I create a test server for testing team with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, architecture

I made a Selenium code by Java to test a certain web-application that our company developed.
Now, developers fix the application quite often and every time they update or fix, testers should test this new version of webapp to assert all functions working fine before application release.

Let's suppose that there are 100 testers who do not know how to run Selenium code or install Java.

I decide to create a testing server so that testers can access this server and run test. They also can see all test histories and details so far as well.

Is it possible and realistic to develop a system that runs like server and client? If yes, Can Jenkins do that? Other solutions are welcome!

Thank you in advance and happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins is one of the tools, you able to use for this, since it provides a simple way to delegate some tasks to already configured envs, nodes share them for multiple users and hide technical complexity. Also this would be aligned to your CI process, e.g. first - deploy the new code to test env, next - run test automation.

But the same also might be said for some other CI tools, so I suggest to pick some CI tool which your development already uses.

The architecture could be:

```
1 CI task for run tests --> 
        2 CI Node or docker image with java, selenium, 
        maven(gradle), it may be some headless Linux --> 
                 3 Selenium cluster which able to launch multiple 
                 selenium sessions (to cover your testers needs). It could 
                 be some selenium cloud service, or configured 
                 onpremise env. -->
                           4 Selenium grid hub (may be headless)-->
                                   5 Selenium grid nodes... The final nodes env 
                                   should match your test requirements. It could 
                                   be Docker with linux (headless or not) or 
                                   Windows/MacOs.
```

- Pick some tools and look for quick start guides/tutorials.
- Start from simple implementation and improve it continuously.

I may say that for many cases Docker + Ubuntu + Headless Chrome is fine, lightweight and rapid.

---

**Some references (examples the tools I've used):**

- Jenkins + Selenium + Maven https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-maven-jenkins-integration/
- Selenoid (selenium grid implementation based on docker containers)  https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid
- Report Portal (just reporting tool) - something more than the default testng report provides. https://reportportal.io/

This is very shortly. The same might be done with a lot of other tools.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is really helpful for my project.

Comment: By far, I successfully installed Selenium hub / node and Jenkins. But stuck in running Java code in Ubuntu. Because I want my Ubuntu server to run the Selenium code. Is there anyway to run Selenium code in Ubuntu, if it is how can I migrate Java project from my PC to Ubuntu?

Comment: @deokyongsong do you have an open question, so you'll be able to share some details and I'll try to help with it?

Comment: you already answered my question. I really appreciate that. For those who seek the relevant problem and solution, please see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/70690589/17030420 Thanks.