# How can I transfer Java project from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04? (NO GUI version)

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu

I am trying to run my Selenium code in Ubuntu server and I saw some articles that Java is indenpendent with OS so I thought my Java selenium code would run without any configurations.

However, when I run my Selenium code in Ubuntu server, it comes out heaps of error followings

```
TestNGSandBox.java:16: error: package org.testng does not exist
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
                        ^
TestNGSandBox.java:16: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
^
TestNGSandBox.java:17: error: package org.testng does not exist
import static org.testng.Assert.assertFalse;
                        ^
TestNGSandBox.java:17: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.testng.Assert.assertFalse;
^
TestNGSandBox.java:18: error: package org.testng does not exist
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
                        ^
TestNGSandBox.java:18: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
^
TestNGSandBox.java:19: error: package org.testng does not exist
import static org.testng.Assert.fail;
                        ^
TestNGSandBox.java:19: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.testng.Assert.fail;
^
TestNGSandBox.java:47: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

The way I transfered the project from Windows was that copied whole project folder and pasted in Ubuntu home directory. Then I just type command like.

`java TestNGSandBox.java`

Many solutions I found are talking about Desktop version of Ubuntu.

I am practically new to Java so there must be something I missed while I am porting. So if you give me a tip, that would be super super great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have not supplied any classpath for the build - org.testng is not part of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

To run the selenium/testNG project on Ubuntu you have to:

1 Install Java
https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java

looks like this is already done since you got more detailed java error messages,
which means you have no required packages.. so

2 Make sure, you have all the required libraries `.jar` files within your project

- org.testng
- org.openqa.selenium

3 You have to compile the class you want to run.

For the project when you have all the files in one directory:

```
javac TestNGSandBox.java -cp testng.jar; selenium.jar; ... other dependencies if needed
```

4 Run the class:

```
java -cp testng.jar; selenium.jar; TestNGSandBox
```

---

But using javac/java for managing projects is time-consuming. Try to look at Maven/Gradle tools, which help to build projects and manage dependencies.

Take a look at some selenium-maven-TestNG project skeletons

- https://github.com/khoamle/selenium-java
- https://github.com/lalit-k/selenium-java-tests
- https://github.com/nusratahmed/maven-selenium-webdriver-testng-example-project